# Android is it better to use a TableLayout or GridView

Tags: android, android-layout, mono, xamarin.android, monodevelop

I am developing an app and I would like to have 12 ImageButtons (3 x 4). centered in the android screen and the center section of the screen where the ImageButtons are located to have a color or gradient background.

Is it best to do this with a TableLayout or a GridView... or maybe something else.  I am a newbie to Mono and Android so any help is appreciated.  I was hoping to do most of the layout in the designer, but I am not sure of the best approach.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

I think `GridView` is better to use as it supports recycling of views. In case of `TableLayout` all the views remain in memory.

Even if the no of buttons increases, `GridView` will take care of it.
Make sure you are implementing view recycling correctly, or otherwise you may have a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

If there are only 12 buttons, a TableLayout would probably be simpler to implement because you don't have to mess with the adapter. If you need scrolling or the number of buttons may increase over time, you would probably be better off going with the GridView.

You may want to look into the GridLayout in the Android Support library v7. It is kind of like the TableLayout but seems simpler to do things like just wrap button into a set number of columns.

Comment: I have implemented it using a TableLayout, but I cannot figure out how to put a background behind the button area.  Can that be done with a TableLayout?

Comment: if the button area is a whole row, set the background attribute on the tablerow